# Comonent's templateurl not rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular2-template

I'm new to angular 2. I had tried building a component named "Header" within that I had placed two files named "Header.component.ts" & "Header.component.html". also configured in app.module.ts files as like below :

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './Header/Header.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HeaderComponent
],
imports: [
   BrowserModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my Header.component.ts looks as like below :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
     selector : 'app-header',
     templateUrl: './Header.component.html'

 })
 export class HeaderComponent{
       HeaderName = 'Its Header';
  }
```

And my Header.comonent.html is like below :`

```
  <h1>
  Header.. {{HeaderName}}
  </h1>
```

And my Index.html looks like below :

```
 <app-header>
 </app-header>

 <app-root>  
 </app-root>
```

In the browser I'm able to view the default one app-root selector correctly. where as the one which I created  I'm not able to render.

My folder structure looks like below image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uusmd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.html you shall only have 
`<app-root></app-root>`

inside app-root template :

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

Comment: Yah sorry, Edited the post. Please check once. If interpolation was the problem, atleast I should get the "Header..". I'm not getting that too.

Comment: What is your selector for App Component? Is it app-root?

Comment: where are you using app-header component, in your problem statement you showed app-header, app-root in index.html. index.html should only have 1 app-root and inside app-root component you shall have app-header.

Comment: So,is it mandatory that our index.html should not contain any other components html. I knew that its a root page. But please clarify can we access any other selectors within the index.html or not ?

Comment: your index.html should only have a root component any other selectors should always be used inside root. AppRoot is like entry point component for angular which you will declare it using bootstrap attribute in app.module.ts. You cannot have multiple selector inside index.html except app-root.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 

 `Header.component.ts`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
     selector : 'app-header',
     templateUrl: './Header.component.html'

 })
 export class HeaderComponent{
     public HeaderName = 'Its Header'; //define as public 
 }
```